# How to install oracle 11g XE and use the data files of another instance (like Postgres)?

Tags: oracle-11g, installation, oracle-xe

I installed Oracle 11g XE in Windows 7 x64, then Windows 8.1 (install new OS, not perform an upgrade of the previously Windows 7 x64 installation). Can be possible to install Oracle 11g XE over the existing directory to use the database that was created with Windows 7 like Postgres do when the Data Directory exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason you can't do this.

Typically, you would perform the following steps.

1. Move the `*.dbf` files found in `%ORACLE_BASE%\oradata\` to a safe place.
2. Move the files found in `%ORACLE_BASE%\fast_recovery_area\` to a safe place.
3. Move the spfile found in `%ORACLE_HOME%\database\spfileXE.ora` to a safe place.
4. Install a new Oracle instance and
5. Configure it with `oracle-xe configure` command.
6. Shut the instance down.
7. Move the data files, control file, spfile and online redo log files back to their previous locations.
8. Star the instance.

You would also need to make sure that you specified the same settings during installation as you used with your previous database (`ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_SID`, listener port etc.), otherwise your instance won't start. Ideally I would recommend you doing silent installation with response files ([described](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#BABBCGHA) in Oracle Database Express Edition Installation Guide for Microsoft Windows). This would ensure that you've used the same settings across operating system upgrades/reinstall.

Comment: Thanks Yasir, I did this before read your answer: zipped the old Oracle directory, installed Oracle over that directory, all changes lost, then stoped Oracle services, renamed the new directory and unzipped the old directory, then started Oracle again and all previously data is usable again.